# RSACng and CngKeyBlobFormat import and export formats

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cng

I have a ASN.1 encoded RSA private key in a pem file in this format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
base64 encoded pkcs8 key
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now, to import it into my `RSACng` object I neeed to follow these steps:

1. Read the file and extract the encoded key
2. Convert `base64` to bytes to get the `byte[]` for pkcs8 key
3. Decode the `byte[]` from ASN.1 (DER) to key information (modulus, exponent etc.)
4. Load these parameters into the `RSACng` object

I have two following questions:

**1. Why doesn't the** `CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob` **allow you to automatically import the PKCS8** `byte[]` **key into the** `RSACng` **object?**

For instance, why couldn't it work in this way:

```
var keyData = GetBytesFromPEM(pemstring); // Get the bytes for key that is ASN.1 DER encoded
CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Import(keyData, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
```

CngKeyBlobFormat clearly specifies that it is a PKCS8 private blob.

**2. What is the ASN.1 encoding format of the** `RSACng.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob)`**?**

I noticed that if I load the key into the `RSACng` as I described above and I then export the same key using the above code, I get the BLOB which is encoded in a different ASN.1 format, and which INSIDE it contains the ASN.1 DER encoded key. Basically, to get information from this exported key I would need to DECODE it from this ASN.1 format again to get the original key parameters stored inside it which are AGAIN encoded in ASN.1 DER.

Why is it such a mess? And is the reason why you cannot import the ASN.1 DER encoded key into the `RSACng` that `CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob` has a different ASN.1 encoding format and it is not DER? Would the potential workaround then be to encode the original RSA private key to that another ASN.1 format, since this is exactly how the key is exported?

EDIT: apparently, `RSACng.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob)` uses Object Identifiers (I'm not yet familiar with that), but it seems to still be in DER format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Why doesn't the CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob allow you to automatically import the PKCS8 byte[] key into the RSACng object?

Because `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` indicates a PKCS#1 `RSAPrivateKey`, not a PKCS#8 `PrivateKeyInfo`.  A PKCS#8 non-encrypted private key would say `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`.

> 2. What is the ASN.1 encoding format of the `RSACng.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob)`?

PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#section-5.

```
  PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version                   Version,
    privateKeyAlgorithm       PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier,
    privateKey                PrivateKey,
    attributes           [0]  IMPLICIT Attributes OPTIONAL }

  Version ::= INTEGER

  PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier

  PrivateKey ::= OCTET STRING

  Attributes ::= SET OF Attribute
```

The value in `PrivateKey` for an RSA key is the PKCS#1 `RSAPrivateKey` value.

> Why is it such a mess? ... Object Identifiers ...

The PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo format is a container for any kind of private key.  The Object Identifier (OID) tells the reader what kind of thing the payload is.  If the OID is `rsaEncryption` (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1) then the payload is `RSAPrivateKey`, if it's `id-dsa` (1.2.840.10040.4.1) then the payload is an INTEGER representing the private key (and the context parameters are in `privateKeyAlgorithm.Parameters`), if it's `id-ecPublicKey` (1.2.840.10045.2.1) (yes "public", 'cuz names) then the payload is an `ECPrivateKey`, et cetera.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So strange that it actually is PKCS#1, because the tool says it's PKCS8. So if I export the PKCS8 and encode it in base64, should I add headers to the file with BEGIN PRIVATE KEY then to show that it is indeed PKCS8?

Comment: If it's an RSA private key in PKCS#8 format and you're adding the PEM armor yourself, then: yes, you should say `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` (without the word RSA).